# OpenLayers + Google maps in Flex, is it possible?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, google-maps, flex4, flex4.5

Recently i really was amazed by openstreet maps, and it's very possibilities to manipulate data, aswell the free of charge about many prescious things - like geocoding and the maps itself.

But i wish to still having a backup behind with google maps.

Is it possible to having both of them in Flex, and how ?
( or at least where i can look for similar project of "unification" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [OpenStreet Maps has a REST API](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/openstreetmap).  You can access that API in a Flex application using the [HTTPService](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/data_access_2.html); assuming a proper crossdomain.xml file is in place.

If not; you'll have to use a proxy between your Flex app and the REST API.

Comment: :( Pitty that there isn't yet a read-to-be-used unification library containing the most popular maps providers. Thank you again about direction, it have some interesting resources in.

Answer (score 1):

[MapQuest](http://www.mapquest.com) has an [Open Flash API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/flash) that uses OpenStreetMap data.  They also offer an [Open Flash Mobile API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/flash-mobile) that can be used with Flash Builder to build apps for the iPhone, Android, and BlackBerry tablet with the new tools in Flex 4.5+.
Feel free to check out the documentation on the [MapQuest Developer Network](http://developer.mapquest.com/)!